# Изнеможённый, изнемождённый, изможённый или измождённый?

Tags: орфография

Встречаются четыре слова:

1. из**немож**ённый
2. из**неможд**ённый
3. из**мож**ённый
4. из**можд**ённый

(выделены части, которые различаются).

Какие из них являются на данный момент нормативными, а какие — нет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Смотрим в словарь:

> 1) ИЗМОЖДЁННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -дён, -дена́, -дено́. Крайне истощённый, изнурённый.
>
> 2) ИЗНЕМОЖЁННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -жён, -жена́, -жено́. Крайне утомлённый, обессилевший, слабый. И. футболист едва держался на ногах. И. путник. // Выражающий изнеможение. И-ое лицо. И. взгляд. И. вид.

Вариант *изможенный* не фиксируется, равно как и *изнеможденный*.